# I did not get the Greeter hat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2015

On biology stack exchange, I had reviewed a new first question and upvoted it. Then I edited it. The edit was definitely in the post body. After I edited it, I did not get the hat so about 20-30 minutes later, I un-upvoted it and upvoted it again.  How come I did not get the Greeter hat then?

Comment: I guess it has to be the network-wide first post, [the user](http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/8825/benjwoodcroft) already gained some reputation on other sites.

Comment: @LuxxMiner thanks, I need to have that confirmed by a mod or somebody like that. BTW, that is the wrong user linked...

Comment: Then please include a link to the question or the user in your question, I just picked the first one in your edited posts that seemed to match the criteria.

Comment: @LuxxMiner [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41742/what-is-the-origin-of-prions) but what you said may still be true

Comment: It says you already have the hat on Biology SE. Did you just receive it, or did you forget you'd already earned it?

Comment: @animuson I just did about 2 min ago

Comment: Hats seem to take a bit of time, so it might even still be for that edit and post.

Comment: Is that confirmed: the first-post new-user target of the edit must be for their FIRST post on ANY SE community or just on the specific one (where it is awarded)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question you link to in the comments is by a user who already had a previous (now deleted) post. You eventually received the hat for a different post.

Comment: So does it mean I shouldn't have deleted [this answer of mine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271308/152859)?